# Accessing records in Android using rawQuery and then displaying

Tags: sqlite, android-fragments

I am working on several rawQueries to use to parse data from a table in Android. The below code works fine and returns the lowest rowid in the table.

```
public void firstRecord(View v){
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM surveyDB WHERE rowid = (SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM surveyDB)",null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    szList.add(c.getString(0));

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sucessful Event. szRowid is: " +szList +".", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I have two questions, and they are both extremely basic: 1) what is the best way to expand the above code to create language to capture the contents of other columns in this table at that specific rowid, (rowid, sampler, species, place), and display this in my application? Something like this perhaps:

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edSpecies)).setText("");
```

with the proper reference replacing "" in `.setText()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
String TABLE_SURVEY = "surveyDB";
String COL_ROW_ID = "rowid";
String COL_SAMPLER = "sampler";
String COL_SPECIES = "species";
String COL_PLACE = "place";

public ArrayList<SurveyRecord> getSurveyRecords()
{
     ArrayList<SurveyRecord> records = new ArrayList<SurveyRecord>();
     String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SURVEY;
     query += " WHERE " + COL_ROW_ID = " SELECT MIN ("
     query += COL_ROW_ID + ") FROM " + TABLE_SURVEY;
     Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
     if(Cursor.moveToFirst())
     {
          do{
              String sampler = c.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_SAMPLER));
              String species= c.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_SPECIES));
              String place = c.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_PLACE));
              String rowId = c.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_ROW_ID));
              records.add(new (rowId,species,place,sampler));
            }while(c.moveToNext())
    }
    c.close();
}

public class SurveyRecord{
         String mRowId;
         String mSpecies;
         String mPlace;
         String mSampler;

         public SurveyRecord(String rowId,String species,String place,String sampler)
          {
             this.mRowId = rowId;
             this.mSpecies = species;
             this.mPlace = place;
             this.mSampler = sampler;
          }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Goes to the first record in the dataset
public void firstRecord(View v){
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM surveyDB WHERE rowid = (SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM surveyDB)",null);
    c.moveToFirst();    
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edRowid))  
    .setText(c.getString(0));
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edSpecies))  
    .setText(c.getString(1));
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edArea))  
    .setText(c.getString(2));   
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edSampler))  
    .setText(c.getString(3));
}
```

Comment: Code posted on 3/3/2014 no longer builds in the latest version of Android Studio. An updated example project is on GitHub here: https://github.com/portsample/simpleDbFrontend